# how to set reference to chrome webpage document using selenium

Tags: vba, selenium

i want to replace the line htmldoc from htmlobject library to something suitable for selenium. i want to pass htmldoc as argument in another subroutine so Here is the code:

```
Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim htmldiv As Selenium.WebElement
Dim htmlul As Selenium.WebElement
Dim htmlAs As Selenium.WebElements
Dim htmlA As Selenium.WebElement
Dim TableName As String

URL = "https://www.whoscored.com/Statistics"
sel.Start "Chrome"
sel.Get URL
 
'set htmldoc= sel.document..... something....
Set htmldiv = sel.FindElementById("top-player-stats")
Set htmlul = sel.FindElementById("top-player-stats-options")
Set htmlAs = htmlul.FindElementsByTag("a")

    For Each htmlA In htmlAs
        TableName = htmlA.attribute("href")
        htmlA.Click
        GoToTable htmldoc, TableName        
    Next htmlA
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Capturing the page source (via selenium) is a bit flaky and might not be what you actually want.

Comment: so how to do that?

Comment: Do what? Capture page source? Again, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to pass htmldocument or selenium variable to another subroutine. will passing selenium webdriver variable work?

Comment: You just want to pass a webelement? Or you want to pass the source code? It's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: Is source code a string if not I want to pass document object

Comment: Please describe what you actually want to. I think what you are likely after is extracting all the href into an array/collection first. Then loop that and .Get each url so as to avoid stale element exceptions etc... Not sure what _GoToTable_ is doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to capture the entire HTML source code.

One options is to use

```
sel.PageSource
```

But that might not behave as you expect as a limitation to how it is generated (source: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource()).

You could also try these after the page is fully loaded:

```
sel.ExecuteScript("return document.documentElement.innerHTML")
sel.ExecuteScript("return document.body.innerHTML")
```

Comment: In what type of variable to store this line sel.Executescript.....